# Configuring Identity for REST Api C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, rest

I'm trying to build an web application that connects with a REST api that uses Identity for authentication. I've made an account controller in which I have placed the login, register and logout methods. The questions I have about these are commented inside the code example. Last thing I struggle with is registering the services. I get the following error message when trying to do the migrations.
Alse I have an ApplicationUser model which inherits from IdentityUser.

Error message when doing the migration:

```
An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[IdentityOef.Domain.ApplicationUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[IdentityOef.Domain.ApplicationUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[IdentityOef.Domain.ApplicationUser]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[IdentityOef.Domain.ApplicationUser]'.)
```

My startup class (REST api):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using IdentityOef.Domain;

namespace IdentityOef.Api
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Is this correct?
            services.AddScoped<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                //Sign-in settings
                //options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            });
            services.AddDbContext<IdentityOefContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityOef")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityOefContext>();
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The AccountController (REST api):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace IdentityOef.Api.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AccountController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly ILogger<AccountController> _logger;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

        public AccountController(
            UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
            ILogger<AccountController> logger,
            IEmailSender emailSender)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
        }

        // Is this correct or should I move this to viewmodels?
        [BindProperty]
        public LoginInputModel LoginInput { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public RegisterInputModel RegisterInput { get; set; }
        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
        [TempData]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        public class LoginInputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
            public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
        }

        public class RegisterInputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            [Display(Name = "Email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
            [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        }

        // Is this the correct url?
        [HttpGet("Login")]
        public async Task LoginOnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
            }

            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

            // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }

        // Is this the correct url?
        [HttpPost("Login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> LoginOnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(LoginInput.Email, LoginInput.Password, LoginInput.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = LoginInput.RememberMe });
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                    return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    // Wat moet hier gereturned worden?
                    return RedirectToPage("Home");
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form

            // What should be returned here?
            // Is this correct?
            return RedirectToPage("Login");
        }

        [HttpGet("Register")]
        public async Task RegisterOnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        }

        [HttpPost("Register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterOnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = RegisterInput.Email, Email = RegisterInput.Email };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, RegisterInput.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(RegisterInput.Email, "Confirm your email",
                        $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                    if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                    {
                        return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = RegisterInput.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form

            // What should be returned here?
            // Is this correct?
            return RedirectToPage("Register");
        }

        // What does this call?
        // Is this the correct url?
        [HttpGet("Logout")]
        public void OnGet()
        {
        }

        // Is this the correct url?
        [HttpPost("Logout")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> LogoutOnPost(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            _logger.LogInformation("User logged out.");
            if (returnUrl != null)
            {
                // Is this correct?
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                // What should I use here?
                // Is this correct?
                return RedirectToPage("Logout");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `// Is this correct? services.AddScoped<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();` -> nope. You're not supposed to register Identity services manually, but rather, register the library using one of the supported methods: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#adddefaultidentity-and-addidentity

Comment: Also, your code has Razor Pages stuff (like `[BindProperty] public LoginInputModel LoginInput { get; set; }`) in a non-Razor Page (`AccountController : ControllerBase`). Nothing there is going to work properly

Comment: This is all boilerplate code. I guess if you have Visual Studio you can create a web API and check the authentication box, choose Individual and the whole thing is generated, and it works. If you can, do that and compare with what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I will look into it, and post when I get further on it!